# Add new directory within subdirectory using CVS

Tags: directory, cvs

How does one add a new directory within a subdirectory using a CVS repository?

```
cvs add [new_dir_name]
```

simply creates a new directory on the first level of the repository, while going into the subdirecory I am interested in and adding does not work. i.e.L

```
cd  repository/directory
cvs add [new_dir_name]
```

Produces an error:

```
cvs [add aborted]: there is no version here; do 'cvs checkout' first
```

(This error message, though, still happens when I check out the repository).

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd  repository
mkdir a
mkdir a/b
mdkdir a/b/c

cvs update -d a/b/c ( not sure if in one go works, if not, try one after another)
```

The option `-d` will create directories that are missing. The same should work for add, if you cvs update afterwards and commit to persist it.

Personally I would use git or svn - changed from cvs ~10y ago

Answer (score 1):

You must add each directory in the path to the final subdirectory that is not present on the server in descending oder.

For example...

If you are in the root of your cvs repository, the following should work.

```
mkdir -p dirname/subdirname
cvs add dirname
cvs add dirname/subdirname
```

alternately / equivalently

```
mkdir -p dirname/subdirname
cvs add dirname
cd dirname
cvs add subdirname
```